# Why I'm getting 403 forbidden error only in one specific route in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel

```
{!!   Form::open(array('recipe' => 'form', 'url' => 'recipe-origin-update/'.$recipeOriginInfo->id, 'files'=> true, 'class' => 'form-horizontal needs-validation', 'novalidate')) !!}
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="card-box zoomIn"  id="animationSandbox">
                <div class="panel-head" style="border-bottom: none !important;">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h4 class="header-title">Update recipe Origin</h4>
                            <p style="font-size: 12px;">Update Origin by filling up the required information.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group position-relative mb-3">
                                <label for="recipe_origin_name">Recipe Origin name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control recipe_origin_name" name="recipe_origin_name" value="{{$recipeOriginInfo->recipe_origin_name}}" required>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    Please enter recipe origin name.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group position-relative mb-3">
                                <label for="recipe_origin_desc">Description</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control fullEditor" name="recipe_origin_desc" id="recipe_origin_desc" maxlength="500" rows="2">
                                    {{ $recipeOriginInfo->recipe_origin_desc }}
                                </textarea>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" type="submit">Update</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

I have found the problem but couldn't understand why this is happening. Problem is inside textarea. When I'm putting the value {{ $recipeOriginInfo->recipe_origin_desc }} inside the textarea and trying to update it, then it giving me 403 forbidden error. But If I don't put the value {{ $recipeOriginInfo->recipe_origin_desc }} inside the textarea, then it works fine. But I need to put the value inside the textarea as this is edit page. How can I solve the issue?

The route is:

Route::post('recipe-origin-update/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\RecipeOriginController@update');

The values of $recipeOriginInfo:
"id" => "5"

```
"recipe_origin_name" => "Chinese Cuisine"
"recipe_origin_img" => "622e29c6e631dchinese.jpg"
"status" => "1"
"recipe_origin_desc" => "<p>History of Chinese cuisine starts with the 4 thousand year old archaeological findings of the oldest noodle food found in the upper reaches of the Chinese Yellow River. By the time of the Han Dynasty, manufacture of various grain food became very organized and cooking also reflected that.</p>"
"created_by" => "1"
"updated_by" => "1"
"created_at" => "2022-03-03 19:58:31"
"updated_at" => "2022-05-20 09:34:25"
```

Comment: Show us the values of `$recipeOriginInfo`, to be sure also show the routes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added the values and the route.

Answer (score 1):

In the text area, you are using HTML tags so you should use {!! !!} instead {{ }}. it should be this way

```
<textarea class="form-control fullEditor" name="recipe_origin_desc" 
 id="recipe_origin_desc" maxlength="500" rows="2">
  {!! $recipeOriginInfo->recipe_origin_desc !!}
  </textarea>
```